# How to Access HTML Inside of Angular Directive (Transclusion)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, web-component, transclusion, angularjs-ng-transclude

I am using angular-ui. I am trying to reduce html coding my making reusable elements with angular directives. I'm definitely missing something. What I want to do is this:

`<modal modal-title="Some Title" button-text="Click Me">Modal Content</modal>`

And I want that to output the modal and button so instead of adding all that markup over and over for the modal I can just use this custom element. It seems to be working except that I can not for the life of me figure out how to get the content inside of the element. Here's the basics of what I'm doing:

```
angular.module('app').directive('modal', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'partials/modal.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: 'modalController',
    controllerAs: 'mCtrl',
    transclude: true,
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.buttonText = attrs.buttonText;
            scope.modalTitle = attrs.modalTitle;
        }
    };
}).controller('modalController', function($scope,$modal,$attrs) {
    var _this = this;
    this.buttonText = $attrs.buttonText;
    this.modalTitle = $attrs.modalTitle;

    this.open = function () {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'modal-content.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'miCtrl',
            resolve: {
                modalTitle: function() { return _this.modalTitle; }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
            //something
        }, function () {
            console.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };

    this.save = function() {
        //something
    };

}).controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, modalTitle) {
    this.modalValue = 1;
    this.modalTitle = modalTitle;
    this.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close(this.modalValue);
    };

    this.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

Here's the template (partials/modal.html)

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modal-content.html"> 
    <div class="modal-header"> 
        <h3 class="modal-title">{{miCtrl.modalTitle}}</h3> 
    </div> 
    <div class="modal-body"> {{ mCtrl.content }} </div> 
    <div class="modal-footer"> 
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="miCtrl.ok()">OK</button> 
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="miCtrl.cancel()">Cancel</button> 
    </div> 
</script>

<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="mCtrl.open()">{{mCtrl.buttonText}}</button>
```

How do I get the content of the element into mCtrl.content? The rest of it works as expected, I'm just missing something. Thanks!

Edit: It seems I need to use transclusion, so this is what I want to do:

`<div class="modal-body"><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>`

But I get this kind of error when I open up the modal:

`[ngTransclude:orphan] Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! No parent directive that requires a transclusion found. Element: <ng-transclude>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular transclude in a directive containing a ng-template (generic Confirm Modal)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29305161/angular-transclude-in-a-directive-containing-a-ng-template-generic-confirm-moda)

Comment: Oh no. I hope not, that's really messy, wish it worked a different way.

Comment: Having spent time on the linked answer, I don't think there is a simpler way - at least not with the current version of `$modal`. Unless, of course, you only want to use a small set of templates, then you can specify the template ID and use `ng-include` in the template of the modal.

Comment: @NewDev how would that work? I would have to make a bunch of templates in the template file?

Comment: Yes, - either a file or `<script type="text/ng-template" id="...">`